# Minicart not working in magento 2.1.2

Tags: magento-2.1, mini-cart

I am working on magento-2.

After added the products into cart, minicart is not showing any products even if the added product exists in the checkout/cart page.

After long refresh, this minicart works.l haven't change the phtml file of the minicart.

Comment: If you are working in locally, then please check you console you will sure have some console error regarding customer data, hit that url in new tab, and refresh your page you will surely get mini-cart data. **Note** :  **whenever we working locally some url's are not cached and sometime customer- data sections giving console error better always to make console clear(without error at-least ).**

Answer (score 0):

**Quick way:**

It is a known bug. Turn on your **FULL PAGE CACHE** to make it work properly.

**Possible fix:**

There is a temporary fix you can apply:

`vendor\magento\module-catalog\view\frontend\templates\product\view\addtocart.phtml`

You simply need to change:

```
"bindSubmit": false
```

to:

```
"bindSubmit": true
```

Source: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/5377 .
It worked for me.